# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'userEditCommand' available as request attribute

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user-edit-form", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String userEditForm(@ModelAttribute("userEditCommand") UserEntity userEntity, BindingResult result, ModelAndView model, @RequestParam("userPhotoPath") MultipartFile file, HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException  {
    ((Model) model).addAttribute("user", new UserEntity());
    return "staff-user-profile";
    //return new ModelAndView("staff-user-profile","user",userEntity);
}
```

staff-user-profile.jsp

```
<form:form class="form-horizontal" action="staff-edit-form" commandName="userEditCommand" enctype="multipart/form-data" modelAttribute="userEditCommand">
   <form:label path="userFirstName" >First name:</form:label>
   <form:input path="userFirstName" value="${user.userFirstName }"/>

   <form:label path="userLastName" >Last name:</form:label>
   <form:input path="userLastName" value="${user.userLastName }"/>

 <form:label path="userAddress" >Address:</form:label>
   <form:textarea path="userAddress" cols="5" rows="3" value="${user.userAddress }"></form:textarea>

    <form:label path="userCity" >City:</form:label>
    <form:input path="userCity" value="${user.userCity }" />
     <form:label  path="userCountryId" >Country:</form:label>
    <form:select path="userCountryId" >
        <form:options items="${countryList}" />
   </form:select>
```

Comment: i know its repeated question but im not able to map request to the model attribute for the above example

Comment: please post the part of the jsp that contains the  `spring:from` tag

Comment: <form:form class="form-horizontal" action="user-edit-form" commandName="userEditCommand" enctype="multipart/form-data" modelAttribute="userEditCommand">

Comment: still im struggling for this but not able to get the answer